# Minimee 2.18 with Cloudfront

Tags: extension, caching, cloudfiles, aws

I'm still quite new to ExpressionEngine

Been messing around with using JohnDWells' Minimee extention to serve minified .css and .js files from cloudfront rather than the site itself (Base URL) using cloudfronts custom origin feature.

It seems to work quite well. Expect Minimee is not detecting changes made to .css and .js files in the Base Path, and doesn't produce an updated combined .css or .js file.

Has andbody else tried this method (I searched, but didn't find anything specific)?

Any sugesstions on what I may (surely) be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out.

For some reason the combined .css and .js files are updated once you update changes to a template.